# Code golf: Reverse quine

Tags: code-golf

Write a program that outputs the **reverse** of its source code as a string. If the source is

```
abcd
efg
```

(i.e., the C string `"abcd\nefg"`)

Then the output should be

```
gfe
dcba
```

(i.e., the C string `"gfe\ndcba"`)

Bonus points for using esoteric languages such as brainf*ck.

---

*EDIT:** Removed the unnecessary \0 characters.+

Comment: Hmm.... This could be quite challenging....

Comment: I hate to be the CW police here, but code golf questions should be community wiki by tradition (check the last 3 or so - all CW).

Comment: Ok, sir! I made it community wiki. :)

Comment: Excellent. Working on a Perl solution as we speak.

Comment: If the input program is "blah\n" should the output be "\nhalb" ?

Comment: I believe there is a typo in your post? The first "quote" and the first c string you posted do not match.

Comment: @strager - I believe so.

Comment: My attempt at a BF reverse quine failed horribly.  I will forever respect someone who manages that.

Comment: Tons of quines here - http://www.nyx.net/~gthompso/quine.htm

Comment: I think if people are going to complain that a program reading its own source is "cheating" (like SilentGhost's Python answer) then that should be mentioned in the rules.

Comment: Please someone move this question to the Code Golf Stack Exchange site.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is code-golf.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn: It is indeed off-topic. When I posted the question, the rules were a lot more relaxed about what constituted off-topic, though.

Comment: I know. But some people don't liked it (whatever), so I usually leave the old questions alone. But if someone posts a new answer...

Answer (score 32):

### C : 0 chars

> 

Ref: http://www0.us.ioccc.org/years.html#1994_smr

Comment: A C compiler will not compile this, so it is technically not C

Answer (score 24):

### HQ9+:

In *HQ9+* esoteric language this code might be:

```
Q
```

Here You can find [interpreter for that language](http://safalra.com/programming/esoteric-languages/interpreters/hq9-plus/).

### Ruby:

Reversed quine from [here](http://www.justskins.com/forums/shortest-nozero-ruby-quine-122609.html).

```
eval s=%q(puts "eval s=%q(#{s})".reverse)
```

Comment: Damn you, sir! I would +1 for beating me to the punch, but I believe this should be community wiki.

Comment: Nice answer! Simple is better!

Comment: Warning--the HQ9+ interpreter locked up Firefox on me.

Answer (score 18):

**Powershell** FTW (1 character):

```
1
```

Put it directly on the command line, or inside a script.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a two-liner, adapted from [NeatQuine.py](http://users.aims.ac.za/~mackay/python/quine/NeatQuine.py):

```
me = 'me = %(me)r\nprint (me %% locals())[::-1]'
print (me % locals())[::-1]
```

Answer (score 7):

### C89

```
int sprintf(char*,char*,...);char*d=
"int sprintf(char*,char*,...);char*d=%c%c%s%c%c,b[999],*p=b+251;main(){for(sprintf(b+1,d,10,34,d,34,10,10,10);*p;)putchar(*p--);}%c"
,b[999],*p=b+251;main(){for(sprintf(b+1,d,10,34,d,34,10,10,10);*p;)putchar(*p--);}
```

Comment: Output has one fewer `,10` in the arguments to `sprintf()` than source.

Comment: Nice use of `putchar(*p--)`. I haven't tested it, but I understood the concept.

Comment: You were still off by a semicolon in the `for()` loop, but that's a trivial fix, so I went ahead and added it. But +1.

Comment: Sorry. It was only one character, so I thought it would be easier.

Comment: @strager: is it actually rude to modify a _community wiki_ answer? Especially when he's not trying to take the credit? Methinks thou dost protest too much.

Comment: @Piazza, He could have modified it if I didn't respond to his comment in a week, or something.  I'm capable of modifying my own code, and I found it offensive he did it for me.  I know this is CW, but that's how I felt.

Comment: I certainly feel free to edit others posts and allow the same privilege in return, even without the Community Wiki thing.  *shrug* Not like there's any hard rules about that here.

Answer (score 5):

### Bash script

**(10 Charecters)**

```
cat $0|rev
```

This must be saved as a script file to work and executed on the same directory.

Another solution would be in python (or any other scripting languages) a zero byte source code file! it will print nothing in return. There's nothing in the rules saying it can't be 0byte file :).

Comment: Quines aren't supposed to read their own source code from the filesystem.

Comment: Following the idea of zero-byte solution, probably any scripting language allow to do the same. So the point is that is not a quine ;-)

Answer (score 5):

### J, 26 characters.

```
|.(,~,2#{:)'|.(,~,2#{:)'''
```

Produces the output:

```
'''):{#2,~,(.|'):{#2,~,(.|
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to lose at golf, but it taught me an important lesson about the subtleties of `reverse()`. **Perl** in **way too many** (142) characters:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$_='#!/usr/bin/perlc%$_=c%s%c%;print sprintf~~reverse,10,39,~~reverse,39,10;c%';print sprintf~~reverse,10,39,~~reverse,39,10;
```

This proves that the `sprintf()`/`reverse()` combination is not the way to approach this problem. A better Perl solution will undoubtedly use `eval()`.

---

Vast improvement: 45 characters:

```
print~~reverse <<''x2
print~~reverse <<''x2
```

Note that the source file should end in a *blank line*. The blank line is counted in the character count - how else do you think we got an odd character count out of two identical lines of code?

Comment: `reverse<<''` works fine, at least on my Perl 5.8.8.  However, isn't this missing a newline at the start of the output?  `print$/.reverse<<''x2` fixes that.

Answer (score 4):

**Python 2** (55 char):

```
x='x=%s;print(x%%repr(x))[::-1]';print(x%repr(x))[::-1]
```

A better golfer might be able to shorten this somewhat, so any improvements are welcome.

Edit (43 char):

```
x='x=%r;print(x%%x)[::-1]';print(x%x)[::-1]
```

also thanks to @stephan202 for catching the whitespace on prints

Comment: fails in python 3. print doesn't return a string that you can reverse. here's the correct solution `x='x=%r;print((x%%x)[::-1])';print((x%x)[::-1])`

Comment: @tor valamo, this isnt written in python 3, and the parenthisis are optional for the print __statement__.

Answer (score 3):

## F# (659 chars)

```
open System;let R(s:String)=new System.String(s|>List.of_seq|>List.rev|>Array.of_list) in let q=char 34 in let Q(s:String)=s.Replace(new String([|q|]),new String([|char 92;q|])) in let Quine s=String.Format("let s={0}{1}{2} in printf {3}%s%s{4} (R(Quine s)) (R s)",[|box q;box(Q s);box q;box q;box q|]) in let s="open System;let R(s:String)=new System.String(s|>List.of_seq|>List.rev|>Array.of_list) in let q=char 34 in let Q(s:String)=s.Replace(new String([|q|]),new String([|char 92;q|])) in let Quine s=String.Format(\"let s={0}{1}{2} in printf {3}%s%s{4} (R(Quine s)) (R s)\",[|box q;box(Q s);box q;box q;box q|]) in " in printf "%s%s" (R(Quine s)) (R s)
```

Inserting line breaks (that break the program, but make it more readable here):

```
open System;
let R(s:String)=new System.String(s|>List.of_seq|>List.rev|>Array.of_list) in 
let q=char 34 in 
let Q(s:String)=s.Replace(new String([|q|]),new String([|char 92;q|])) in 
let Quine s=String.Format("let s={0}{1}{2} in printf {3}%s%s{4} (R(Quine s)) (R s)",
    [|box q;box(Q s);box q;box q;box q|]) in 
let s="open System;
       let R(s:String)=new System.String(s|>List.of_seq|>List.rev|>Array.of_list) in 
       let q=char 34 in 
       let Q(s:String)=s.Replace(new String([|q|]),new String([|char 92;q|])) in 
       let Quine s=String.Format(\"let s={0}{1}{2} in printf {3}%s%s{4} (R(Quine s)) (R s)\",
           [|box q;box(Q s);box q;box q;box q|]) in " in
printf "%s%s" (R(Quine s)) (R s)
```

Answer (score 3):

In C , 217 chars :

```
a="};)01(rahctup;)--p*(rahctup);p*;43=p*(rof;)a(ftnirp;))a,b=p(tacrts(nelrts=+p{)p*rahc(niam;}7393422{=]99[b;";b[99]={2243937};main(char*p){p+=strlen(strcat(p=b,a));printf(a);for(*p=34;*p;)putchar(*p--);putchar(10);}
```

Comment: Length could be shortened more because i also added EOF at the end.
If you use "cmp" command on Linux system, it points out that EOF is missing.

Answer (score 3):

**Javascript** - IE/Chrome/FF

```
(function(){alert(("("+arguments.callee+")()").split("").reverse().join(""))})()
```

Answer (score 3):

At the Python interactive prompt:

```
xatnys dilavni :rorrExatnyS
```

27 characters.

Answer (score 2):

## C89, 119 characters

Unfortunately, this requires use of the highly non-standard function `strrev()`:

```
main(){char*a="};)43,)b(verrts,43,a(ftnirp;)a(pudrts=b*,%c%s%c=a*rahc{)(niam",*b=strdup(a);printf(a,34,strrev(b),34);}
```

Answer (score 2):

### [Bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 75 chars

Well, of course an empty shell script will output nothing, but the next best thing I can think of:

```
a=\;printf\ \"a=%q%s\"\ \"\$a\"\ \"\$a\"\|rev;printf "a=%q%s" "$a" "$a"|rev
```

Same ol' trick.

Answer (score 2):

UNIX shell:

```
z=\' a='z=\\$z a=$z$a$z\;eval echo \$a\|rev';eval echo $a|rev
```

I tend to repeat my self: these programs ought to be referred to as `Goedels' because the idea behind a majority of such things was first used (in modern times) by Kurt Goedel in the proof of his First Incompleteness Theorem (Kurt Goedel's Collected Works I, p.175).

Answer (score 1):

#### Perl

73 characters.

```
#! /opt/perl/bin/perl
seek DATA,0,0;$/=\1;print reverse <DATA>;
__DATA__
​
```

- You have to have `__DATA__` at the end for the `DATA` file-handle to start out opened.
- Setting `$/` to a reference of a number, causes `readline()` to read that many bytes at a time.
- `seek(DATA,0,0)` is required to set the pointer to the beginning of the file, instead of at the beginning of the `__DATA__` section.
- Could remove, or shorten the shebang line (`#!` ...)
- `__DATA__` requires a newline after it, or it isn't valid Perl.

Answer (score 1):

### [Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/), 79 characters

```
a=";main=putStr.reverse$\"a=\"++show a++a";main=putStr.reverse$"a="++show a++a
```

Standard trick.

Answer (score 1):

**Java:**

Definitely not the shortest possible, but what the heck (one line):

`public class R{public static void main(String[] a){StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer("public class R{public static void main(String[] a){StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer();s.reverse();System.out.print(s.substring(0,152));System.out.write(34);System.out.print(s);System.out.write(34);System.out.println(s.substring(152));}}");s.reverse();System.out.print(s.substring(0,152));System.out.write(34);System.out.print(s);System.out.write(34);System.out.println(s.substring(152));}}`

Answer (score 1):

**PHP 36 bytest**

```
<?echo strrev(join(file(__FILE__)));
```

Comment: Drop another few? <?=strrev(join(file(__FILE__)));

Answer (score 1):

## C89 (155 bytes)

```
#define q(k)r(char*s){if(*s)r(s+1);putchar(*s);}main(){r(#k"\nq("#k")\n");}
q(#define q(k)r(char*s){if(*s)r(s+1);putchar(*s);}main(){r(#k"\nq("#k")\n");})
```

Answer (score 0):

### PHP

Snip - removed incorrect answer

And now to redeem myself;

```
<?php echo strrev(file_get_contents(__FILE__)); ?>
```

Comment: It's not asking to reverse the input.  It's asking to print out the source program in reverse.

Comment: The goal is to print the program's source code in reverse, not arbitrary user input. Read the Wikipedia article on quines: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_%28computing%29

Comment: bugger. my first attempt at code golf and i misunderstood. :(

Comment: :) Don't worry, this is not a serious contest, there's no limit to how many entries you may post!

Comment: It's generally considered cheating to read from the source file, but I'm glad you've got the objective now.

Comment: Wow ok, so yeah this is a lot trickier than I originally anticipated.

Comment: @Christian - Same here. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

**python** (34 chars):

```
print(open(__file__).read()[::-1])
```

Comment: The rules for writing a quine don't allow reading its source in from a file, including its own source.  That misses the point.

Comment: half of all the answers do exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript: How many characters do you want?**
**SECOND SIMPLEST VALID PROGRAM (using my method): 240 Chars! (including spaces but not new lines)**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var string = "<!DOCTYPE HTML>\n<html>\n" + document.documentElement.innerHTML + "\n</html>";
var string2 = string.split("").reverse().join("");
document.write(string2);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

### **C/C++:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    char c;
    freopen("thisfilename.c","r",stdin); //or thisfilename.cpp
    while(scanf("%c",&c)!=-1)
        printf("%c",c);
return 0; }
```

Comment: Opening the source code file and printing it in reverse is, in a sense, cheating. Not that other people have not done it, of course.